# Hi I need help in streaming image in my JSP page

Tags: java, image, jsp, servlets, outputstream

Okay, so I have created a music uploading website that uploads OGG music. It also has an audio tagger incorporated. I also put the album art into my database as a string.

Now, I want to display that string (representing my album art) to my JSP:

```
@WebServlet(name = "LoadAlbumArt", urlPatterns = { "/LoadAlbumArt" })
public class LoadAlbumArt extends HttpServlet {
   /** 
    * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code> methods.
    * @param request servlet request
    * @param response servlet response
    * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
    * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
    */
   protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
         HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
      response.setContentType("image/jpg");
      try {
         OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
         DBConnector bConnector = new DBConnector();
         PreparedStatement preparedStatement = bConnector
               .Connect("SELECT * FROM devwebmp3.musicdatabase where musicno = ?");
         preparedStatement.setInt(1,
               Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("musicno")));
         ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
         Blob blob = null;
         String imagestring = null;
         while (resultSet.next()) {
            imagestring = resultSet.getString("albumart");
         }

         //BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(ImageIO.createImageInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64Coder.decode(imagestring.toCharArray()))));

         //outputStream.write(blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length()));
         byte[] hello = Base64Coder.decode(imagestring);
         //ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", outputStream);
         //System.out.println("byte" + hello);
         outputStream.write(hello);
         outputStream.flush();
         outputStream.close();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         // ...
      }

      // ...
   }
}
```

In addition, this is the java servlet page:

```
src=<%="\"LoadAlbumArt?musicno="+request.getParameter("musicno") +"\""%>>
```

Comment: @CengizCan     sorry, my question is why is that it is not appearing on my website?

Comment: What do you mean by saying "it is not appearing on my website"?
Any error message/code?
What container or application server do you use?
What browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, where do you call this `processRequest(..)` method?

Are you sure that you included a call for `processRequest(..)` in that servlet's `doGet(..)` method like this:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
                                   throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(req,resp);
}
```

Did you check the output of a known record by requesting

```
http://.../LoadAlbumArt?musicno=1
```

Does your Servlet properly response with a JPEG image? If not, then you should check your Servlet code.

Also change your expression in your View page to this:

```
<img src="/LoadAlbumArt?musicno=${param.musicno}" />
```

Those JSP scriptlets and expressions (`<% %>` and `<%= %>`) are antique relics now, you should NEVER use them unless you have some old code to resurrect.

You didn't give enough details about your database table, BLOB field, even there are random commented code in your question which is hard to decide whether you used them or not.